# React Native TouchableOpacity is auto clicked

Tags: javascript, react-native

I put console.log('Hello') to my button, to testing my button is work or not (actualy im using this button for navigation), but when i try to reload my app, my console show Hello. I didn't press my button yet, but when i try to press it my console didn't show hello.
*Sorry for my bad english*

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, TouchableOpacity, Image} from 'react-native';
import s from './SFooter';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const Footer = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  let active = 0;
  return (
    <View style={s.footerWrapper}>
      <View style={s.iconsWrapper}>
        <View style={s.iconWrapper}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={(console.log('asda'), () => navigation.navigate('Home'))}>
            <Image
              style={s.icon}
              source={require('../../assets/icon/home.png')}
            />
            {active == 0 ? <View style={s.iconActive} /> : <View />}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={s.iconWrapper}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
              style={s.icon}
              source={require('../../assets/icon/book.png')}
            />
            {active == 1 ? <View style={s.iconActive} /> : <View />}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={s.iconWrapper}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
              style={s.icon}
              source={require('../../assets/icon/newspaper.png')}
            />
            {active == 2 ? <View style={s.iconActive} /> : <View />}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={s.iconWrapper}>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Image
              style={s.icon}
              source={require('../../assets/icon/user.png')}
            />
            {active == 3 ? <View style={s.iconActive} /> : <View />}
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

Comment: And my head is snipping around this onPress={(console.log('asda'), () => navigation.navigate('Home')). what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do check your code twice. You cannot call any function directly onPress. what i mean to say is following

Wrong:

```
   <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={(console.log('asda'), () => navigation.navigate('Home'))}
```

Correct

```
   <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => (console.log('asda'), () => navigation.navigate('Home'))}>
```

Comment: What different if i use (console.log('asda') without arrow function?

Comment: brother without arrow function you will going to execute it on every render of component. which is nonsense as we want click to be performed. so to avoid such silly bugs. () => is there to rescue. as this function will be called instead executing everything in onPress on rerender or render

Comment: Thanks for your answer brother :)